# Is $\lnot\lnot\forall x(A(x)\vee\neg A(x))$ a theorem of intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I have a short question. I know that $\neg\neg(A\vee\neg A)$ is a theorem of intuitionistic logic. What about $\neg\neg\forall x(A(x)\vee\neg A(x))$?

Comment: The formula in the text: $\lnot \lnot \forall x ( \ldots)$ is not a theorem of [IL](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/)

Comment: Obviously, neither the formula in the title is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not. To prove this, we can give a countermodel (I'll use Kripke semantics).

For a world $v$ in a Kripke model $M$, the meaning of $M,v\Vdash\lnot\lnot\forall x(A(x)\lor \lnot A(x))$ is: for all worlds $v'\geq  v$, there exists a world $v''\geq v'$ such that for all worlds $w\geq v''$ and all $x\in M_{w}$, $A(x)$ holds at $w$ or for all worlds $w'\geq w$, $A(x)$ does not hold  at $w'$.

In other words, there is a dense set above $v$ of worlds $v''$ with the property that the truth value of $A(x)$ does not ever "flip" for any element of any world above $v''$.

For our countermodel, take the frame to be $\mathbb{N}$ with its usual order, $M_n = \{0,\dots , n\}$, and interpret $A$ in $M_n$ as $M_n\setminus\{n\}$. Then $M,0\not\Vdash\lnot\lnot\forall x(A(x)\lor \lnot A(x))$, since for any world $n$, the truth value of $A(n)$ "flips" when moving from $n$ to $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.  If it were, then using the internal language of a topos, the interpretation of the formula $\lnot\lnot \forall p : \Omega, p \lor \lnot p$ would be $\mathrm{true}$ on any topos.

However, consider the topos of sheaves of sets on $\mathbb{R}$.  In this topos, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have a global section of $\Omega$ corresponding to the open subset $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ x \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  For this section $p$, we get $\lnot p = \emptyset$, so $p \lor \lnot p = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ x \}$.  Taking the intersection over all $x$, we see that $\forall p : \Omega, p \lor \lnot p$ must evaluate to $\emptyset$, and so $\lnot\lnot \forall p : \Omega, p \vee \lnot p$ also evaluates to $\emptyset$ instead of to $\mathrm{true} = \mathbb{R}$.

(Actually, in this argument, there is nothing all that special about the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ that we used.  Pretty much the same argument would work on any $T_1$ topological space with no isolated points.)

Comment: I'm confused by the application of topos semantics here, in particular the quantification over $\Omega$ inside the double negation. I thought that intuitionistic validity meant: for any sheaf $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and any subsheaf $A\hookrightarrow F$, the interpretation of the formula on $F$ comes out to be "true" (the terminal sheaf on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: I guess to expand that part of the argument a bit more, what I'm saying is: for each global section $p_0 \in \Omega(1)$, we have the interpretation of $\forall p : \Omega, p \lor \lnot p$ on 1 is less than or equal to the interpretation of $p_0 \vee \lnot p_0$.

Comment: Oh, unless your question is: in your statement, I'm taking the case of $F := \Omega$ and $A$ is the subsheaf corresponding to $\operatorname{id} : \Omega \to \Omega$.

Comment: Hmm... but if $A$ is the identity subsheaf, which corresponds to the formula $\top$, then $A\lor\lnot A$ is again $\top$, and $\forall x\, \top$ is again $\top$, this time as a subsheaf of the terminal sheaf $1$, and $\lnot \lnot \top$ is $\top$. Maybe the confusion is this: the way I understand it, the semantics of $\forall$ is not an intersection, as you suggest in your answer, but rather the right adjoint to the pullback from subsheaves of $1$ to subsheaves of $F$.

Comment: No, $A$ is not the identity subsheaf, it's the pullback of $\mathrm{true} : 1 \to \Omega$ along $\operatorname{id}_{\Omega}$, i.e. it's the monomorphism $\mathrm{true} : 1 \to \Omega$.  So, in this case where $\Omega_{\mathbb{R}}$ is canonically isomorphic to the sheaf $U \mapsto \{ V \subseteq U \mid V \mathrm{~open} \}$ (with restriction maps $\rho_{UV} : W \mapsto W \cap V$), the subsheaf is $U \mapsto \{ U \}$.

Comment: And yes, the interpretation of $\forall$ is not quite an intersection - in this case it would be $U \models \forall p : \Omega, p \lor \lnot p$ (i.e. the interpretation on $U$ is equal to $\mathrm{true}$) if and only if for all morphisms $V \to U$ and sections $p_0 \in \Omega(V)$, $V \models (p \lor \lnot p)[p / p_0]$.  But in this case, taking $p_0$ of the form $U \setminus \{ x_0 \}$ for $x_0 \in U$, and identity morphism $U \to U$, already suffices to show that $U \not\models \forall p : \Omega, p \lor \lnot p$ if $U$ is nonempty.  (Slight restatement of my argument there.)

Comment: Ah-ha, I see I got confused between "the identity subsheaf" and "the subsheaf corresponding to the identity"! I understand the example now, thanks a lot for explaining.